# Python Linked List issue

Tags: python, linked-list

I've hit a snag working with classes on a linked list. My code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, data, next_item = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_item = next_item

    def get_item(self):
        return self.data

    def set_next(self, setnext):
        self.next_item = setnext

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_item

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self,item):
        temp = Item(item)
        temp.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = temp

    def find(self, item):
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            if current == item:
                print "Found It!"
            else:
                current = current.get_next()

    def print_list(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            print node.get_item()
            node = node.get_next()

    def size(self):
        counter = 0
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            counter += 1
            current = current.get_next()
        print counter

    def insert(self,item,lpos):
        current = self.head
        while current != lpos:
            current = current.get_next()
            if current == None:
                return None
            else:
                item_insert = Item(item, lpos.next_item())
                lpos.set_next(item_insert)

myList = LinkedList()
myList.add(1)
myList.add(2)
myList.add(3)
myList.insert(8,2)
```

When i run this code the method (insert) fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 72, in <module>
    myList.insert(8,2)
  File "main.py", line 56, in insert
    item_insert = Item(item, lpos.Item.next_item())
  AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'Item'
```

The insert method will allow you to add a node to your linked list at a specified point, and carry out with rearranging the proper pointers, considering the insert.

please advise!

Comment: You seem to have dropped a line of the error message.

Comment: Why would you copy a traceback and skip most essential information - exception itself?

Comment: @Rogalski Sorry, I cut that off by mistake. I've added it in now

Comment: The code for `insert` is so broken that it's not even clear what it's trying to do.  If the `lpos` argument supposed to be an index into the list, with 0 being the first position, 1 being the second, etc.?  Or is it supposed to be a data value that you're searching for, with the intent of inserting the new element ahead of any match that's found?

Comment: Why traceback shows different code from you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't pay attention to the difference between 'item' and 'index'. The index is a unsigned digit present for the position of the item in the list, however the item is a node in the list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, data, next_item = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_item = next_item

    def get_item(self):
        return self.data

    def set_next(self, setnext):
        self.next_item = setnext

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_item

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self,item):
        temp = Item(item)
        temp.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = temp

    def find(self, item):
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            if current == item:
                print "Found It!"
            else:
                current = current.get_next()

    def print_list(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            print node.get_item()
            node = node.get_next()

    def size(self):
        counter = 0
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            counter += 1
            current = current.get_next()
        print counter

    def insert(self,item,lpos):
        if lpos == 0:
            item_insert = Item(item, self.head)
            self.head = item_insert
            return
        current = self.head.get_next()
        previous = self.head
        index = 1
        while index != lpos:
            index += 1
            previous = current
            current = current.get_next()
            if current == None:
                return None

        item_insert = Item(item, current)
        previous.set_next(item_insert)

myList = LinkedList()
myList.add(1)
myList.add(2)
myList.add(3)
myList.insert(8,0)
myList.print_list()
```

Comment: thanks for your help on this. I'm a beginner at Python and i'm still learning the basics of how classes/methods/functions work. I appreciate your insight. Regardless, your code works!

Answer (score 0):

lpos is an index, which type is `int`. But what you want to set is `Item.next_item()`, of course it doesn't work. Change:

```
# lpos is Int
item_insert = Item(item, lpos.next_item())
```

to:

```
# use Item instance to do your stuff
item_insert = Item(item, current.next_item())
```

Anyway, your implementation of insert should not be correct.